# React form will only update firstestore document when all inputs have been changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My react form for updating profile data currently only interacts with firestore when all inputs have been changed.

Current Error;

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" @ profileActions.js:10:4

Things I have tried checked;
- Props dispatching to 'updateProfile' function - working
- Changing 'onChange' function to 'onSubmit' - didn't work
- Adding required to all input fields - didn't work
- Replacing defaultValue with placeholder - didn't work

Profile.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateProfile } from "../../actions/profileActions";
import Password from "./Password";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: this.props.profile.firstName,
    lastName: this.props.profile.lastName,
    businessName: this.props.profile.businessName,
    phoneNumber: this.props.profile.phoneNumber,
    email: this.props.profile.email
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log.apply(this.state);
    this.props.updateProfile(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    const { profile, profileError, auth } = this.props;
    if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
return (
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <form className="m-4" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} to="/profile">
      <div>{/* FIX - red line appears when bg-white removed below */}</div>
      <div>
        {/* FIX - form only submits correctly when all inputs have been changed */}
      </div>
      <div
        className="alert-danger rounded col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mx-auto bg-white"
        style={{ color: "#ff0000" }}
      >
        {profileError ? <p>{profileError}</p> : null}
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1" />
        <div className="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 d-flex flex-column mx-auto">
          <div className="col-stretch rig-bot profile-label">
            <h5 className="">First name :</h5>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="col-stretch rig-bot profile-label">
            <h5 className="">Last name :</h5>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="col-stretch rig-bot profile-label">
            <h5 className="">Business name :</h5>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="col-stretch rig-bot profile-label">
            <h5 className="">Phone number :</h5>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="col-stretch rig-bot profile-label">
            <h5 className="">Email :</h5>
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 d-flex flex-column">
          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              className="form-control"
              defaultValue={profile.firstName}
              autoFocus
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastName"
              className="form-control"
              defaultValue={profile.lastName}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="businessName"
              className="form-control"
              defaultValue={profile.businessName}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="tel"
              id="phoneNumber"
              className="form-control"
              defaultValue={profile.phoneNumber}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-label-group">
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              className="form-control"
              defaultValue={profile.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" />
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-4 cen-mid mx-auto">
          <input
            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-md"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <Password />
    <div className="y-100" />
  </div>


 );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
    profileError: state.profile.profileError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateProfile: profile => dispatch(updateProfile(profile))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Profile);
```

profileActions.js

```
export const updateProfile = props => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const userId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
    const firstName = props.firstName;
    const lastName = props.lastName;
    const initials = props.firstName[0] + props.lastName[0];
    const businessName = props.businessName;
    const phoneNumber = props.phoneNumber;
    const email = props.email;
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .update({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        initials: initials,
        businessName: businessName,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        email: email
      })
      .then(
        firestore.collection("auditProfile").add({
          userId: userId,
          action: "update",
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          businessName: businessName,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          email: email,
          changedOn: new Date()
        })
      )
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PROFILE" });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR", err });
      });
  };
};
```

I currently have no rules attached to my firestore database and am really hoping the solution is something super stupid like; "firestore won't allow you to use update function if fieldValues are identical".

My brain has currently turned to mush so have given up. Please help?

Thanks in advance for anyone who gives this any time :)

Comment: Did not understand this ` Changing 'onChange' function to 'onSubmit' - didn't work -` ?

Comment: @Panther Sorry.. bad explanation.. changed all onChange={this.handleChange} to onSubmit={this.handleChange} to see what would happens so the event of the value being changed wasn't reliant solely on the input being changed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to point out is that you're setting the values in state in your `onChange`, but then never using those values in your inputs - you get `defaultValue` from `props`, but never assign `value={this.state.profile.firstName}` etc.

The error you're seeing points to `props.firstName` or `props.lastName` in profileActions.js being null/undefined (trying to access the 0th index on null/undefined will throw a TypeError). Are you setting initial values for those anywhere?

I'd suggest getting `value` for each of your inputs from state, and make sure you have initial data for first and last names.